# Calendar front page

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I would like to make a calendar front page like this [here](http://www.rjt.org.uk/home/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/2010Calendarsmall.pdf). Can someone help me please?

Here is what I have done untill now (but it doesn't work):

```
\documentclass[ngerman,landscape,fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}

\renewcommand{\date}{2015}

\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,backgrounds, calc}
\pagecolor{black}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[white] at ($(current page.center) (0,-10cm) $) {\fontsize{40}{48} \textcolor{white}{\scshape calendar --} \textcolor{red}{\date}}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (januar) at (?,?) {example-image};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the following? Replace the picture names like `goldshade` with your own pictures.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,landscape,fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}

\renewcommand{\date}{2015}

\usepackage[margin=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,backgrounds, calc}
\pagecolor{black}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\edef\myspace{2mm}
\edef\wsingle{\the\dimexpr(\linewidth-\myspace*5)/6\relax}
\edef\hsingle{\the\dimexpr1.2\dimexpr\wsingle\relax}
\edef\wdouble{\the\dimexpr\wsingle*2+\myspace\relax}
\edef\hdouble{\the\dimexpr\hsingle*2+\myspace\relax}
\edef\wraster{\the\dimexpr\wsingle+\myspace}
\edef\hraster{\the\dimexpr\hsingle+\myspace}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{-12mm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont\textcolor{white}{\scshape calendar --} \textcolor{red}{\date}
\end{center}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[fill overzoom image=example-image-a] (0,0) rectangle +(\wdouble,\hdouble);
\fill[fill overzoom image=blueshade]       (0,\hraster*2) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\fill[fill overzoom image=goldshade]       (\wraster,\hraster*2) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);

\fill[fill overzoom image=example-image-a] (\wraster*2,0) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\fill[fill overzoom image=example-image-b] (\wraster*3,0) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\fill[fill overzoom image=goldshade]       (\wraster*2,\hraster) rectangle +(\wdouble,\hdouble);

\fill[fill overzoom image=example-image-a] (\wraster*4,0) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\fill[fill overzoom image=goldshade]       (\wraster*5,0) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\fill[fill overzoom image=example-image-b] (\wraster*4,\hraster) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\fill[fill overzoom image=blueshade.png]   (\wraster*5,\hraster) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\fill[fill overzoom image=goldshade.png]   (\wraster*4,\hraster*2) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\fill[fill overzoom image=blueshade.png]   (\wraster*5,\hraster*2) rectangle +(\wsingle,\hsingle);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work on my computer. I get these error (line 34-47): "! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/fill overzoom image' and
I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it." What to do and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BasiliusSapientia You need `\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}` with `tcolorbox` in a recent version for it. You will need at least version `3.00 (2014/05/08)`. After updating `tcolorbox`, the option `fill overzoom image` should work.

Comment: thank you very much! And it is nice to see package inventors like you helping us user :-)