# How to install the newest TeXLive version on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: texlive, linux

Because of [tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215825/calendar-front-page/215836?noredirect=1#comment506834_215836) I need the newest version of TeXLive! But how to get it on Linux Mint 17 Qiana Cinnamon? I tried to install it with some PPA's which doesn't worked. What to do?

Kind regards!

Comment: you should consider installing TeX Live manually (not using a pre-packaged version from PPAs). It's very easy on Linux: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200209/what-are-the-benefits-of-vanilla-texlive-over-texlive-provided-by-ubuntu-reposit for some discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer also replies your last question about TeXLive 2014/2015 (that is cooking yet).

In Mint usually you have not installed TeXlive base (as Ubuntu) so you don't need to uninstall anything before. You can download from the CTAN an iso file with the TeXLive 2014 compilation from here http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2014.iso or if you prefer it, there is a [script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texlive/eitl) that you can use for install it too.

In the case of the iso image, be sure you have installed the `perl-tk` library before because otherwise you won't be able to run the GUI of the installer. For TeXlive 2015 (available next summer) you can use a very similar path, now you can use TeXlive 2014 if you need the ultimate release of the packages.