# Installation of TeXLive 2014/2015 on Linux?

Tags: linux

I have TeXLive 2013 on my Linux Mint Cinnamon 17. Is there any possibility to get TeXLive 2014/2015? Because I need usepackages like "tcolorbox", which aren't in TeXLive 2013 Version.

Kind regards!

Comment: How did you install TL2013? There are instructions on this site, here they are: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/32374

Comment: [quick install for unix](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). Many linux users prefer a vanilla TL.

Comment: To get a more up-to-date version of TeXLive you need to install manually as is covered in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216290/how-to-install-the-newest-texlive-version-on-linux-mint-17). The location will be different than where your TL2013 is so you'll need to change the IDE paths so they compile using TL2014-5.

Comment: @darthbith Cinnamon appears to be using the same TeX Live package as Ubuntu 14.04. Worse still is their "rolling release" Debian edition that [stalled in 2014](http://www.zdnet.com/article/the-future-of-lmde-and-derivatives/), and apparently now tracks Debian stable (which rolls *very* slowly).

Comment: @MikeRenfro The answer in that link explains how to install vanilla TL on Ubuntu (upon which Linux Mint is based, IIRC)... I guess DJP provided a more direct answer for Linux Mint :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really the right person to describe an installation on Linux, since I do not use Linux. But, by chance, I installed Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.1 on an old computer for test purposes some months ago. I also managed to set up the recent TeXLive. Basically, I followed [TeX Live - Quick install](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), which worked with small variations.

The following is by memory:

- I downloaded [install-tl-unx.tar.gz](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz)
- I used the Nemo explorer from Linux Mint to extract the `ìnstall-tl-20150124` directory from the downloaded tarball.
- I opened a terminal window from the context menu of Nemo inside this installation.
- Inside the terminal, I used `sudo install-tl` after some failed attempts to follow the instructions from [TeX Live - Quick install](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) (they omit the `sudo` which make Linux dummies like me stumble).
- I do not remember, if the running installation script asked me about setting up pathes. If it did, I guess I answered *'yes, do it'*. But I'm very sure that I did not change anything later manually because I simply do not know where... ;-)

That's the installation guide from somebody who is blind on Linux. My system was a vanilla Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.1. In your case, you may have to do something with the pathes since you already have an old TeXLive (??).

After this base installation, updating is really very easy by calling `sudo tlmgr update -all` in a terminal window. One can put this into a *starter* for the desktop (right click on the desktop to create one).

Comment: From the Quick install page: "Of course, you need to have permission to write into the destination directory, but TeX Live itself does not care if you are root or not." -- so if you chose to install TL in your home directory, you could. (I wouldn't recommend it.) Otherwise, the standard thing, for me at least, is to `su`, not `sudo` :-)

Comment: In any case, it would be beneficial to not forget the "dummy" package mentioned in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/32374. In this way your system will _know_ that TeX and friends is installed and will not try to install them again as dependencies for other packages. You will also be able (or forced, probably) to uninstall your distribution's TeXLive, which is probably not bad.