# Best way to tile images in LaTeX

Tags: tables, graphics

In my document I need quite often tiled arrangements of images. I could tile the images externally using e.g. Matlab or Gimp. However I dislike this unflexible approach.

I found another way of tiling images, which comes close to what I want: [How to build and combine sophisticated layouts in figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43010/how-to-build-and-combine-sophisticated-layouts-in-figures)

However, the latter way is not handy in terms of flexible arrangements: I could not easily achieve something like this with only one caption below: [image: Three tiled images. One column at the left with a big image, two small pictures in a column at the right.]
Also the borders in between those pictures cannot easily be achieved.

What is the best way of getting this done? Tables?

Comment: Just a few days ago we had [Arrange images as tables or subfigure or some other layout](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288141)

Comment: Maybe, this is a starting point for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215825/calendar-front-page/215836#215836

Comment: Oh thank you! I think I missed those results during my research, because I looked for the keyword "tiling" or "tile". In this case this question can be closed.